# How to sum on a calculated property?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I'm sure I'm guilty of trying to apply SQL logic to Core Data, but even after reading the Apple docs I'm still not sure of the correct approach.

What would be the best strategy for summing the difference of two date properties in a Core Data entity? I have a "numHours" calculated property on the "appt" class but not in the xcdatamodel. The code below fails with a "keypath not found in entity" error. Many thanks for any advice.

## from appt class

```
- (float)numHours {
    float hours = ([self.endTime timeIntervalSinceDate:self.startTime] - [self.durationOfBreak intValue]) / 3600.00;
    return hours;
}
```

## attempt at fetching sum of "numHours" property

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"appt" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];
NSPredicate *datePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date >= %@ && date < %@", self.startDate, self.endDate];
[request setPredicate:datePredicate];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

NSExpression *numHoursPath = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"numHours"];
NSExpression *hoursSum = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"sum:"
                                                   arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:numHoursPath]];

NSExpressionDescription *debitExpressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[debitExpressionDescription setName:@"totalhours"];
[debitExpressionDescription setExpression:hoursSum];
[debitExpressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSDecimalAttributeType];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:debitExpressionDescription]];
[debitExpressionDescription release];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

Jeffery,

You cannot fetch based upon an attribute that isn't actually in the model. The error message, "keypath not found in entity," plainly says this. You can confirm this for yourself by browsing the SQLite DB and you'll see there is no attribute for the SQL to query. Hence, your fetch request must fail. `NSExpression *numHoursPath` is a valid expression. It can be applied to collections after you've fetched them. You just cannot use them in a fetch request.

Andrew