# Calculate a Summary with a CoreData relationship

Tags: objective-c, ios, math, core-data

In my object graph, I have two entities in a classic parent/child relationship. Each child has a number of properties, but the one I'm interested in is a time value (stored as an NSDate).

So my parent object has a "Summary" property, which should be the calculated total of it's combined children's time values. Simply: Each child stores an amount of time, I want the parent to display the combined total for all it's children.

I'm moderately experienced with CoreData, and I can easily think of a few ways to achieve this (e.g., it'd be pretty easy to define a transient property on the parent that enumerates the child entities and adds the totals with an ivar) - but I'm wondering if CoreData has an inherent and more elegant solution...

Comment: Does time mean duration? If so, you could store times as `float`s or `double`s and use the `@sum` operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this problem:
first - get your data to NSSet or NSArray and use @sum operator:

```
//assume that `childs` are NSArray of your child entities and ammount is attribute to sum
NSNumber *sum=[childs valueForKeyPath:"@sum.ammount"];
```

second is using specific fetch [for specific value](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW6) with added [NSExpressionDescription](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSExpression/expressionForFunction%3aarguments%3a) with a sum. This way is harder but better for larger db's

Comment: You may be able to help with this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862341/how-to-sum-on-a-calculated-property , sounds like you have the knowledge for it.